# Flash AS3 eval()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm new in AS3. I have 15 sounds in my fla; I imported them to the library and exported all sounds with the name `s1, s2, s3, ... s15`

I created a function that recieve the number and then play the sound.

In AS2 I could use `eval` like `eval("s" + n)`, but in AS3 I can't!

My AS3 code is:

```
function PlaySound(Num:Number=NaN) {
    var mySound:Sound = new ["s"+Num](); 
    mySound.play();
}
```

Obviously I'm getting an error!

Someone could help me?

Best, Flávio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent AS3 code would be:

```
var soundClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("s" + Num) as Class;
var mySound:Sound = new soundClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these sound objects in an array, say arr["s1"]=s1 ,arr["s2"]=s2 and so on,( yes in AS3 an array is actually a hashmap.)

Once that is done, its a piewalk, whenever you receive the number (Num) do this

```
function PlaySound(Num:Number=NaN) {
  var mySound:Sound = arr["s"+Num];
  mySound.play();
}
```